# Why is cd appending dirs like pushd?

Tags: zsh, cd-command, oh-my-zsh, pushd

I am using zsh in [Babun](http://babun.github.io/) (Cygwin with oh-my-zsh and some extras).

I noticed some odd behavior, it looks like `cd` is behaving like `pushd`?

```
{ ~ }  » mkdir foo
{ ~ }  » pushd foo
~/foo ~
{ foo }  » popd
~
```

The above is fine and expected, but see the below.

```
{ ~ }  » cd foo
{ foo }  » dirs
~/foo ~
```

I tried checking if there was some alias being set somewhere, but I saw no such thing.

```
{ foo }  » alias | egrep "(cd|pushd)"
-='cd -'
1='cd -'
2='cd -2'
3='cd -3'
4='cd -4'
5='cd -5'
6='cd -6'
7='cd -7'
8='cd -8'
9='cd -9'
grt='cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel || echo ".")'
pu=pushd
```

Why is my `cd` appending `dirs`? It's not really a problem, I am more just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see now. oh-my-zsh does `setopt auto_pushd` which is described [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions) as:

> **AUTO_PUSHD** (**-N**)
>
> - Make **cd** push the old directory onto the directory stack.